# Warning: move_uploaded_file() not working. failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: php, html

I want to upload an image using php, but the following script is not working. I have attached html, php codes also with error i am getting. Please help me to solve this error.

PHP Code->>>

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Html code->>>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Error i am getting->>>

[image]

Comment: You should give the folder `755` or `777` rights. (Called CHmod)

Answer (score 0):

You should put your full path for upload dir `$target_dir = __DIR__ .  'uploads/';`.

And check if it has rights to write files.

Comment: after i used full path i am getting following error- Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/phpprojects/smartview/admin105/file/uploads/pic.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpprojects/smartview/admin105/file/upload.php on line 38

Comment: I think it's not full path from root directory.

Answer (score 0):

As warning say you don't have folder permission to read/write folder contains.

Try this thing.

1.Change the owner of uploads

`sudo chown user` replace user with your user using `whoami` command

2.Chmod uploads.

`sudo chmod -R 0755 uploads`